# how to validate NZBN code number of NewZealand?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working on app needs an NZBN Code to register with stripe payments, when a user can enter any NZBN that cause Stripe issues,
i entered the https://api.business.govt.nz/services/v4/nzbn to check it but no obivious api call contain the real check of the NZBN code .
is there any way please ?
**EDIT:**
i am passing the NZBN number as tax_id to Stripe so Stripe check it with what ever api and tell me that the tax_id is not a valid nzbn , but when i put a valid nzbn it takes it correclty how to prevent entering a not valid NZBN before going to stripe

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do with Stripe and isn't working as you expect? Are you doing something in the API or in the Dashboard etc? Are there any error messages you can share?

Comment: @NolanH i am passing the NZBN number as tax_id to Stripe so Stripe check it with what ever api and tell me that the tax_id is not a valid nzbn , but when i put a valid nzbn it takes it correclty how to prevent entering a not valid NZBN before going to stripe

Answer (score 2):

This is a really old question but it has no answer, so I thought I'd share;

NZBN (different from the NZ GST number) is a plain old GTIN 13. This is my TypeScript for checking for 1) a valid GTIN, and then 2) a GTIN13 specifically

```
/**
 * Boolean function to test code against GTIN published checksum method(s)
 */
export function isGTIN(text: number | string): boolean {
  try {
    const r = /[\D]/g,
      gtin = typeof text === "number" ? text.toString().replace(r, "") : text.replace(r, ""),
      paddedValue = gtin.padStart(14, "0")
    if (!gtin.match(/^(\d{8}|\d{12,14})$/)) return false
    let result = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < paddedValue.length - 1; i += 1) {
      result += parseInt(paddedValue.charAt(i), 10) * (i % 2 === 0 ? 3 : 1)
    }
    return (10 - (result % 10)) % 10 === parseInt(paddedValue.charAt(13), 10)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message)
    return false
  }
}

/**
 * Boolean function to test NZBN (GTIN13) against published checksum method
 */
export function isNZBN(text: number | string): boolean {
  try {
    const r = /[\D]/g,
      gtin = typeof text === "number" ? text.toString().replace(r, "") : text.replace(r, "")
    // NZBN is a GTIN 13
    if (gtin.length !== 13) return false
    else return isGTIN(gtin)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message)
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could rely on validation error instead of implementing this yourself, you can also optionally pre-validate the input. This is really up to you.

Validation follows the [OECD TIN specifications](https://www.oecd.org/tax/automatic-exchange/crs-implementation-and-assistance/tax-identification-numbers/), such as for [NZ IRDs](https://www.oecd.org/tax/automatic-exchange/crs-implementation-and-assistance/tax-identification-numbers/New%20Zealand-TIN.pdf), which looks to be 8 or 9 numeric digits. If the NZBN has a different spec than this, you'd need to implement a validation check before submitting.

Comment: nzbn is 13 digits ,i am sorry ! but your answer is not related with what i ask!

Comment: OECD doesn't have a spec posted for that and nor does the NZBN registry website. They don't even provide example IDs, so I'm not sure how anyone could know that. Is this a valid tax number?

Comment: And where are you using this value? Is it part of an account update call? For example, for `company.tax_id`? You say you have this validated in some cases already? You can perform format validation on such a value ahead of time, but for full validation you'd have to wait for the account webhook after updating.